# Campo referente ao MAX

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela/campos:

**Tabela: PLANOS**

- `ID` (PK)
- `VEICULO` (REPETE-SE)
- `DATAINCLUSAO`
- `REVISAO` (UNIQUE)

Preciso trazer o número da `REVISAO` de cada `VEICULO` da última `DATAINCLUSAO`.

Assim consigo trazer o `VEICULO` e a última `DATAINCLUSAO`, mas se coloco `REVISAO`, irá pedir para adicionar no `GROUP BY`, e não posso, pois o `REVISAO` é único, então me traria tudo.

Se coloco `MAX(REVISAO)` poderá me trazer valor incorreto.

```
SELECT VEICULO, MAX(DATAINCLUSAO)
FROM PLANOS
GROUP BY VEICULO
```

---

Resumindo: o que preciso é trazer o valor de `REVISAO`, referente a última `DATAINCLUSAO` de cada `VEICULO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Além da resposta já dada, também é possível com uma subconsulta equivalente usando `max()`:

```
SELECT P1.VEICULO, P1.DATAINCLUSAO, P1.REVISAO
FROM PLANOS P1
WHERE P1.DATAINCLUSAO =
       (SELECT MAX(P2.DATAINCLUSAO)
        FROM PLANOS P2
        WHERE P2.VEICULO = P1.VEICULO)
```

[Exemplo no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/526d9/14)

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de fazer:

```
SELECT      P1.VEICULO
        ,   P1.REVISAO
        ,   P2.DATAINCLUSAO
FROM        PLANOS  P1
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      MAX(DATAINCLUSAO) AS DATAINCLUSAO
                        ,   VEICULO
                FROM        PLANOS
                GROUP BY    VEICULO
            )       P2  ON  P2.VEICULO      = P1.VEICULO
                        AND P2.DATAINCLUSAO = P1.DATAINCLUSAO
```

É uma *query* mais segura porque tem o filtro do veículo, para além da data.

Se acontecer ter mais do que um veículo na mesma data, esta *query* não lhe devolve mais do que um resultado por veículo.

Comment: Sua resposta está correta, mas eu não me atentei e faltou um pedaço crucial na pergunta: "A possibilidade da query sem *subquery*!"... Caso não exista, irei aceitar a resposta com subquery, pois a pergunta servirá como fonte de pesquisa. Obrigado e desculpe-me a falha! ;)

Comment: Sem a _subquery_ não vai conseguir, porque precisa da última data de inclusão de cada veículo, o que obriga automaticamente a ter outra consulta.

Comment: é isso aí que o @JoãoMartins falou! +1 na resposta tb

Answer (score 1):

Você pode controlar isso em uma subconsulta, onde ordena-se pela `datainclusao`, carregando apenas o mais recente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VEICULO, DATAINCLUSAO, REVISAO 
FROM PLANOS P1
WHERE P1.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 P2.ID 
               FROM PLANOS 
               WHERE P1.VEICULO = P2.VEICULO 
               ORDER BY DATAINCLUSAO DESC)
```

Comment: Sua resposta está correta, mas eu não me atentei e faltou um pedaço crucial na pergunta: "A possibilidade da query sem subquery!"... Caso não exista, irei aceitar a resposta com subquery, pois a pergunta servirá como fonte de pesquisa. Obrigado e desculpe-me a falha! ;)